# jQuery DataTables "No Data Available in Table" in Google Web App

Tags: html, jquery, google-apps-script, datatables

I am running "03_datatables.html" with Google Web Application. After the page is loaded, it starts the data extraction process. It adds the relevant rows to the "tbody" element after pulling the data. But I can't filter my data because it gives "No data available in table" error. How can I solve this problem?

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frfhr.png

Code.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('03_datatables').evaluate();
}


function getTableData() {

  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var vs = ss.getSheetByName('Data'); 
  var data = vs.getRange(2, 1,vs.getLastRow()-1, 6).getValues();
return data;


}
```

03_datatables.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.2/af-2.3.7/cr-1.5.4/date-1.1.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/kt-2.6.4/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.3/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.5/sb-1.2.1/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/dataTables.uikit.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.2/css/uikit.min.css"/>




  </head>
  <body>
    
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body">
  


        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.2/af-2.3.7/cr-1.5.4/date-1.1.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/kt-2.6.4/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.3/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.5/sb-1.2.1/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>





$(document).ready(function() {
  
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
 
    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;
 
                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }        
    });
 
 
} );



  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData();


  });

function generateTable(dataArray)
{
      var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

        dataArray.forEach(function(r){  

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
              var col = document.createElement("td");
              col.textContent = r[i];
              row.appendChild(col); 
  
              
        }
        tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
}


  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are going to build the HTML table by using `tbody.appendChild(row);` then you need to do this _before_ you initialize the DataTable. See the [HTML (DOM) sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html) example, where the HTML table is already created before the "document ready" event fires.

Comment: The more common approach is to pass the table data directly to DataTables, as JSON. There are various ways to do this - see the [Ajax and JavaScript examples](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/index.html).

Comment: My problem was solved when I put the codes inside the "$(document).ready" function at the end of the "generateTable" function. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), so other people can see the code of the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved when I put the codes inside the "$(document).ready" function at the end of the "generateTable" function. Thank you so much.

EDİT HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.2/af-2.3.7/cr-1.5.4/date-1.1.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/kt-2.6.4/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.3/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.5/sb-1.2.1/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.css"/>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.2/css/dataTables.uikit.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.2/css/uikit.min.css"/>




  </head>
  <body>
    
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table-body">
  


        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.11.2/af-2.3.7/cr-1.5.4/date-1.1.1/fc-3.3.3/fh-3.1.9/kt-2.6.4/r-2.2.9/rg-1.1.3/rr-1.2.8/sc-2.0.5/sb-1.2.1/sp-1.4.0/sl-1.3.3/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script>


  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getTableData();


  });

function generateTable(dataArray)
{
      var tbody = document.getElementById("table-body");

        dataArray.forEach(function(r){  

        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
              var col = document.createElement("td");
              col.textContent = r[i];
              row.appendChild(col); 
  
              
        }
        tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );
 
    // DataTable
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var that = this;
 
                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
        }        
    });
}


  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```